# java libraries for exporting models TO blender

Tags: java, blender

I am starting a project where I would like to generate some 3D data sets (scenery from minecraft in my case) and export them for use in a blender (the 3D rendering tool) project.

Are there any java libraries that make it easy to write files for use by blender?

If not, where are the specs for an approriate file readable by blender (something that can hold 3D geometry and texture info)?

Comment: Blender can import many formats OBJ being one of them. You can export vertices, faces, normals and texture coordinates an obj file and material definitions(reference to texture, etc.) in an MTL file, both ascii and [documented](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavefront_.obj_file). You can either whip out a quick exporter from scratch or look for a library

Comment: I have had success generating OBJ files and importing them into blender.  The big thing that is missing is any ability to specify lighting.  I wonder if there's another format that could be used to specify all the lights.

Comment: Another technique I have developed lately is generating "data scripts" which are python code.  I then write the python functions that use the blender python API to insert the objects into the scene using the parameters provided by the data script. http://web.purplefrog.com/~thoth/coral/blog.html, see addLump(x,y,z,t) .

Comment: That's a really cool project! Thanks for sharing, it's nicely documented. Perhaps you could add it as an answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

George Profenza pointed out that blender can import Wavefront-style OBJ files and provided a [wikipedia link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavefront_.obj_file) I was able to use to write a java library which is currently available from github : https://github.com/mutantbob/jwavefrontobj

A different technique I have been using on more recent projects is to use Blender's python API.  The general idea is that you write software that emits the various bits of scenery as python method calls.  You then hand-craft the definitions of those python methods to build the object inside blender.  http://web.purplefrog.com/~thoth/coral/blog.html provides many examples, but it only scratches the surface of what can be accomplished in blender.

I seriously doubt I am a pioneer in this space.  It has probably been used by various scientific visualizations for years.

Example videos include

- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=57IEQ87KRN0 where the simulated explosions generate several data streams (destroyed blocks, incandescent spheres, explosion light sources)
- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9r9Q6MIUdsA where the background scenery was generated by java and emitted as python.  The character was animated by hand.